# glew-config.cmake include files do not exist

Tags: cmake, glew, find-package

find_package(GLEW CONFIG) of cmake finds glew-config.cmake file. It is OK. But, glew-config.cmake produces errors because two of the include files  do not exist. I am pasting those two lines from glew-config.cmake file below:

```
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/glew-targets.cmake)
include(${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/CopyImportedTargetProperties.cmake)
```

I couldn't find glew-targets.cmake and CopyImportedTargetProperties.cmake in anywhere. I built glew from source. Am I missing something or can it be related with building process of glew?

Comment: "I built glew from source." - You need to **install** it after the building. And point CMake to the installed variant of `glew-config.cmake`.